# Executing External Applications From Service

Tags: delphi, service

I'm trying to run external Application from service,

I've tried different solutions but nothing works so far.

`ShellExecute` I found out it cannot be used from a service

and `WinExec`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run  applications from a service, but since Vista you won't see them at the users dektop.

Running the taskmanager will show that applications are started nevertheless.
[MSDN Interactive Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There are existing mechanisms to interact with the desktop yet, but that would be beyond the frame.
[Launching an interactive process from Windows Service in Windows Vista and later](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Services run in session 0, but that's a non-interactive session. So if the other process is interactive you need to make sure that it runs in an interactive session. That's quite trick to arrange, but not impossible. Details can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx